# How to get all values from all DateTime fields, without hard-coding the field names?

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a table, tabEvent, with 11 fields that are DateTime.  I want to query every DateTime field in tabEvent, and if any values are > '4/1/2014' and < dateDate(), then return that row.

But I don't want to hard-code the field names, because they are always changing (the site is growing and morphing constantly).

I have the snippet below which returns me the field names, but is not a query on the table (yet).

```
select c.name ColumnName
from sys.columns c
join sys.types t on (c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id)
where object_name(c.OBJECT_ID) = 'tabEvent'
  and t.name = 'datetime'
order by c.OBJECT_ID
```

English translation: I'm trying to code a proc that will, each time I log into the admin page, check the tabEvent table for any key dates that have passed (since the last notification) and send a message to me, the admin.  Then it will update the notification-date value to today, for next time's running of the proc.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @Startdate VARCHAR(10)= '2014-04-01' 
DECLARE @EndDate VARCHAR(10) = convert(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),20)

DECLARE @sql nVARCHAR(max)

DECLARE @where nVARCHAR(max)
SELECT @where = ' WHERE ' +  STUFF((select c.name  + ' BETWEEN ''' + @StartDate + ''' AND ''' + @EndDate + ''' AND '
from sys.columns c
join sys.types t on (c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id)
where object_name(c.OBJECT_ID) = 'tabEvent'
  and t.name = 'datetime'
order by c.OBJECT_ID
FOR XML PATH('')),1,0,'')

SELECT @sql =   'SELECT * FROM tabEvent' + LEFT(@where,LEN(@where)-4)

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```